# Does 'from' in this example mean 'some'?

Tags: meaning

> I have chosen for you from the best of our personnel.

Can 'from' here also mean 'some'?

> I have chosen for you some of the best of our personnel.

Comment: What are you talking about, I just need the meaning of the word. Example and or definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, no, it doesn't *mean* that.  You can replace "from" with "some" and get a grammatical sentence with very similar meaning, but the meaning is not identical: the sentence with *from* means that the speaker chose *from among* the best of the personnel, while the sentence with *some* means that *what the speaker chose* was a selection of the best personnel.

The actual results are probably not distinguishable, unless the "from" sentence refers to a single selected candidate, but they're saying different things; in the "some" version, the candidate pool is unspecified and may have included the full set of personnel, while in the "from" version, the candidate pool itself is restricted to the best personnel.  And, of course, "some" cannot properly refer to a single individual.

Comment: Damn, you got there first.  The biggest distinguisher I can see is that in the first case, the speaker could have said this having chosen a single person.  Using "some" in that case would be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, *from* doesn’t mean *some*, but you could make two different sentences that mean roughly the same thing:

> I’ve chosen some of the best. . . .

or

> I’ve chosen from among the best. . . .

Answer (score 0):

No.

For example, a single person could have been chosen which would not indicate *some* were chosen, but that person would have been among the best.